# Download icon file and use it for Setup Icon File in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

In order to make my setup file lighter I wish to download the icon file with IDP plugin put it in {tmp}  and use it for  the setup icon file? how can it be done?

Comment: I don't think you are saving on the right place. Icon files are small in size, so I would include them in setup. Btw. which icon are you going to load that way (which `[Setup]` directive, or which parameter) ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Icons are very small, and bitmaps used in the setup are compressed until the setup program is expanded. Doing anything with either of them to make your setup file "lighter" is actually going to make it larger (with the added overhead of the IDP plugin and bandwidth used to download the file and loading of the icon at runtime from disk).

Comment: you are right in general, but 
1. my icon file size is big 
2.  use IDP for many other files so either way I will add it.
I need to know how to tell `SetupIconFile` to take the file from {tmp} and if i cant do that, is there a way to replace the setup icon file?

Comment: [`SetupIconFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_setupiconfile.htm) is used at compile time, and embedded in the executable. There is no way to make this dynamic, as none of the setup's code will be running at the time.

Comment: The `SetupIconFile` directive specifies icon for the setup binary. Why would you want to assign an icon for the file that the user executed (and of which the user already seen the icon) ?

Comment: Is there a way to overtake this icon file from the code section?

Comment: No. That icon is compiled into the executable (as a result you will see the setup binary with that icon). Even if that was possible, why would you set icon for the *.exe file that you just executed ? That makes no sense. The `SetupIconFile` cannot be set at runtime. At runtime, it would make more sense to assign an icon e.g. for the `UninstallDisplayIcon`, or for shortcut icons, but not for the icon of the setup itself.